# how to set value in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have 4 dropdown list in my form, but when i want to set the selected value the first 2 ddl, always follow value the next 2 ddl.

**aspx.cs**

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    for (int hours = 0; hours <= 23; hours++)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = hours.ToString();
        li.Value = hours.ToString();
        ddlDepartHours.Items.Add(li);
        ddlArrivalHours.Items.Add(li);
    }

    for (int mins = 0; mins <= 55; mins+=5 )
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = mins.ToString();
        li.Value = mins.ToString();
        ddlDepartMins.Items.Add(li);
        ddlArrivalMins.Items.Add(li);
    }

    ddlDepartHours.SelectedValue = "1";
    ddlDepartMins.SelectedValue = "5";
    ddlArrivalHours.SelectedValue = "10";
    ddlArrivalMins.SelectedValue = "50";
 }
```

this is the link of the result : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/ibte.png/

Comment: Please clarify your requirement properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you are inserting the same objects as list items for both "hours" as well as both "minutes" DDLs. Later on when you are setting the selected value of the one of them, effectively you are setting corresponding `ListItem` object as selected, which of course affects one DDL in which this object is also added.

Solution here is to insert different objects in different, though similar, dropdowns:

```
ddlDepartHours.Items.Add(new ListItem(hours.ToString(), hours.ToString()));
ddlArrivalHours.Items.Add(new ListItem(hours.ToString(), hours.ToString()));
```

The same for the minutes:

```
ddlDepartMins.Items.Add(new ListItem(mins.ToString(), mins.ToString()));
ddlArrivalMins.Items.Add(new ListItem(mins.ToString(), mins.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of the object in the second `ListItem li = new ListItem();`

Answer (score -1):

Add items like this

```
ddlDepartHours.Items.Add(new ListItem(hours.ToString(), hours.ToString()));
ddlArrivalHours.Items.Add(new ListItem(hours.ToString(), hours.ToString()));

ddlDepartMins.Items.Add(new ListItem(mins.ToString(), mins.ToString()));
ddlArrivalMins.Items.Add(new ListItem(mins.ToString(), mins.ToString()))
```